# When do you usually use roswtf?

Tags: ros, roswtf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I dont know roswtf using exactly

When do you usually use roswtf?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35395/when-do-you-usually-use-roswtf?/) by [rosmaker](https://answers.ros.org/users/2491/rosmaker/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2012-05-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [roswtf wiki page](http://ros.org/wiki/roswtf#What_does_roswtf_look_for.3F) gives a decent explanation of when to use it. If you think something in your ROS system is not working properly, roswtf has a few plugins to try and debug such errors.

Personally, I always end up using [rxgraph](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rxgraph) to debug a large majority of graph issues.

---

Originally posted by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) with karma: 2871 on 2012-06-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2